# Union in thrift shows all values setted in c++

Tags: c++, thrift

I made a simple union of three fields

```
union example{
    1:string STRING,
    2:i64 INT64,
    3:double DOUBLE
}
```

And I instantiate the example union in the client as:

```
example ex;
ex.__set_STRING("Example");
ex.__isset.STRING = true;
```

And send the example via a method that accepts example as an argument

In the server, the method that's called is done like this:

```
void get(const example &ex)
  {
    cout << ex.__isset.STRING << ' ' << ex.__isset.INT64 << ' ' <<
        ex.__isset.DOUBLE << endl;
    cout << ex << endl;
  }
```

And oddly the output for such a small program is:

```
1 1 1
example(STRING="Example", INT64=0, DOUBLE=0)
```

I don't know if this is the proper way of setting the union type, but I tried several combinations and none seems to work.

The sources for the snippet can be found here: https://github.com/enriquefynn/union_thrift

Comment: After `example ex;` try `memset(&ex, 0, sizeof(ex));`

Comment: Or manually setting `__isset.INT64 = __isset.DOUBLE = false;`

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't work :/

Comment: Please post the code that thrift generates for both the client and server side serialization.

Comment: I just appended this code to the tutorial cpp code. The problem is easy to reproduce.

Comment: Given that this problem is about a specific library, it would be hard to find either someone who already has it or someone who's willing to download it and set it up in order to try to solve the issue. It will be better if you post the actual code, and people can glance at it and maybe figure out the problem.

Comment: ok, the code can be found here: https://github.com/enriquefynn/union_thrift

Comment: You are aware of the fact that [`_type_ex__isset` is a bitfield](http://pastebin.com/raw/T5JkunZw)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
uint32_t type_ex::write(::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot) const {
  uint32_t xfer = 0;
  apache::thrift::protocol::TOutputRecursionTracker tracker(*oprot);
  xfer += oprot->writeStructBegin("type_ex");

  xfer += oprot->writeFieldBegin("STRING", ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_STRING, 1);
  xfer += oprot->writeString(this->STRING);
  xfer += oprot->writeFieldEnd();

  xfer += oprot->writeFieldBegin("INT64", ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_I64, 2);
  xfer += oprot->writeI64(this->INT64);
  xfer += oprot->writeFieldEnd();

  xfer += oprot->writeFieldBegin("DOUBLE", ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_DOUBLE, 3);
  xfer += oprot->writeDouble(this->DOUBLE);
  xfer += oprot->writeFieldEnd();

  xfer += oprot->writeFieldStop();
  xfer += oprot->writeStructEnd();
  return xfer;
}
```

Looks like a bug with unions. The values are written unconditionally, whcih is right for `struct` but not for `union`. Consequently, the workaround would be to add an explicit `optional`:

```
union type_ex
{
    1 : optional string STRING,
    2 : optional i64 INT64,
    3 : optional double DOUBLE
}
```

Which gives us:

```
uint32_t type_ex::write(::apache::thrift::protocol::TProtocol* oprot) const {
  uint32_t xfer = 0;
  apache::thrift::protocol::TOutputRecursionTracker tracker(*oprot);
  xfer += oprot->writeStructBegin("type_ex");

  if (this->__isset.STRING) {
    xfer += oprot->writeFieldBegin("STRING", ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_STRING, 1);
    xfer += oprot->writeString(this->STRING);
    xfer += oprot->writeFieldEnd();
  }
  if (this->__isset.INT64) {
    xfer += oprot->writeFieldBegin("INT64", ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_I64, 2);
    xfer += oprot->writeI64(this->INT64);
    xfer += oprot->writeFieldEnd();
  }
  if (this->__isset.DOUBLE) {
    xfer += oprot->writeFieldBegin("DOUBLE", ::apache::thrift::protocol::T_DOUBLE, 3);
    xfer += oprot->writeDouble(this->DOUBLE);
    xfer += oprot->writeFieldEnd();
  }
  xfer += oprot->writeFieldStop();
  xfer += oprot->writeStructEnd();
  return xfer;
}
```

[Bug report filed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3650).