# How to see which "union" attribute is set in a Thrift IDL?

Tags: thrift

I have a Thrift IDL as below:

```
union Container {
  1: Point point;
  2: Polygon polygon;
}
```

If I have a `Container` object, how can I check whether the `Container` is a `Point` or a `Polygon`? Seems like it should be a trivial thing to check, but I can't figure out how...

```
Container container = <some-container>
Point point = container.getPoint(); // will error if the container is a polygon
Polygon polygon = container.getPolygon(); // will error if the container is a point
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `isset` flag and ...

- have a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35514398/499466), and
- the JIRA tickets summarized under [THRIFT-3650](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3650).